# How to fix slow scan rate in SocketMobile Scanner 7Ci?

Tags: socketscan

We've been using the socket scanner in our warehouse for scanning inventory items. We have an iPad application which connects to Socket Scanner to read data off barcodes.

Off late, the scanner is taking a long time to scan. The very first scan completes quickly as expected, but the subsequent scans take a long time ( usually 7-8 seconds). We restarted the scanner, unpaired and re-paired the scanner, did a factory reset, but the issue persists.

Socket Scanner Model: Socket Mobile 7Ci
Host Operating System: iOS 10.3.2

Is there any way to know what might be affecting the scan rate?

Also,
Please check the video which explains the issue in detail:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dyzj5t7vseunw1y/VID-20170916-WA0001.mp4?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, when we did the Factory Reset, the Bluetooth on the iPad was ON and the scanner was connected. It beeped, but actually did not do a Factory Reset.

Looks like scanning Factory Rest Barcode is effective only when Bluetooth is off in the device ( And scanner disconnected from iPad). We switched off Bluetooth in the iPad and scanned the Factory Reset Barcode. The scanner played a music tone and switched itself off. When we powered it on scanned barcodes, there was no delay at all.

The trick is to do a Factory Reset of the device the right away.

Link for SocketMobile Manual:
http://www.socketmobile.com/docs/default-source/series-7/chs-1d-imager-user%27s-guide.pdf